# Docker Redis: Version "6.0.8" in ".\docker-compose.yml" is invalid

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I am using Docker desktop for Windows - community edition, version 2.4.0.0 (2020-09-28) follow tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrFeRwJjWHI ,

File `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "6.0.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

I run command

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\docker>docker-compose up
ERROR: Version "6.0.8" in ".\docker-compose.yml" is invalid.

D:\docker>
```

but error
[image]

I see at here https://hub.docker.com/_/redis has version 6.0.8 . How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version tag is used for specifying docker-compose reference version. You need to choose between existing versions. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

If you want to set redis version you need to use image tag

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.8
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing between version of docker-compose and redis. Use value `3.0.8` .

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/